# Regular expression doesn't work

Tags: php, regex

I need to match following pattern using php Regular expression but it doesn't give expected out come.

ex:-
need to match pattern
 5555 5545 9930

```
$id = "4567 3423 4567";
$regex = "/^[1-9]\d{4} \d{4} \d{4}$/";
if (preg_match($regex, $id)) {
   // Indeed, the expression "^[2-9]\d{2} \d{3} \d{4}$" matches the date string
   echo "Found a match!";
}else {
   // If preg_match() returns false, then the regex does not
   // match the string
   echo "The regex pattern does not match. :(";
}
```

Comment: You're a digit short on the first two sections.

Comment: Try `"/^[2-9]\d{2,3} \d{3,4} \d{4}$/"` or - if you do not want to match mixed input types - `"/^(?:[2-9]\d{2} \d{3}|\d{4} \d{4}) \d{4}$/"`

Comment: Any feedback? You actually did not mention if you need to support both string formats, or just re-vamp the existing one into a different pattern.

Comment: it always goes to "The regex pattern does not match."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match: 4 non-zero digits + space + 4 digits + space + 4 digits

`^([1-9]){4} \d{4} \d{4}$` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I think the safest way to modify the existing regex is by adding an alternative to the first `[2-9]\d{2} \d{3}`:

```
^(?:[2-9]\d{2} \d{3}|\d{4} \d{4}) \d{4}$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF2mU6/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[2-9]\d{2} \d{3}|\d{4} \d{4})` - one of the alternatives:

  - `[2-9]\d{2} \d{3}` - a digit from `2` to `9`, any 2 digits, a space and 3 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{4} \d{4}` - 4 digits, space, 4 digits (for the new string types)
- - a space
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/m1OyOR):

```
$id = "4567 3423 4567";
$regex = "/^(?:[2-9]\d{2} \d{3}|\d{4} \d{4}) \d{4}$/";
if (preg_match($regex, $id)) {
    echo "Found a match!";
} else {
    echo "The regex pattern does not match. :(";
}
```

Comment: Did it finally work for you? Do you need more assistance with this task?

Answer (score 0):

Simple edit of your regular expression will be

```
^[1-9]\d{3} \d{4} \d{4}
```